# Python: Generate autodoc with Sphinx on a single module?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-apidoc

I'm working on a Python library that only has a single .py module and I'm trying to generate documentation for it from the docstrings. I have Sphinx set up and ran through the spinx-quickstart script, but when I try to run (while in the docs directory)

```
sphinx-apidoc ../cffiwrap.py -o .
```

But it just says:

```
../cffiwrap.py is not a directory.
```

Is there some other Sphinx script to autodoc a single file? I thought about just running it against `..` but then I figured it would run in to my tests directory and try to generate docs from my unit tests...

Answer (score 2):

This short [blog post](https://tobywf.com/2019/08/running-sphinx-on-a-single-python-file/) seems to show an alternative way to generate an automatic api doc for a single module. Copied here for convenience and persistence:

Place the `conf.py` file at the same directory as your module:

```
import os
import sys

# enable autodoc to load local modules
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("."))

project = "<project>"
copyright = "year, author"
author = "author"
extensions = ["sphinx.ext.autodoc", "sphinx.ext.intersphinx"]
exclude_patterns = ["_build", "Thumbs.db", ".DS_Store"]
templates_path = ["_templates"]
html_theme = "alabaster"
html_static_path = ["_static"]
intersphinx_mapping = {
    "python": ("https://docs.python.org/3", None)
}
html_theme_options = {"nosidebar": True}
```

Add this `index.rst` next to it

```
<project>
=========

.. automodule:: <project>
   :members:
```

Finally, replace `<project>` with your module name, `pip install sphinx` and run:

```
sphinx-build -b html . _build
```

Answer (score 0):

The manual says:

> sphinx-apidoc [options] -o  packagedir  [pathnames ...]
>
> where pathnames are the directories to exclude.

So try:

```
sphinx-apidoc -o . .. ../test_dir
```

where `test_dir` is where your tests live.

Comment: The manual does mention a way to exclude pathnames, but I don't think your syntax is correct. Anyways, I'll try it with just excluding the tests directory.